# Alternate vim mapping

Tags: substitute, map-operator

I have a file that looks something like this

```
\usepackage{tex/Forkurs-1p-2p-laererutdanning-2018-V}

\usepackage{../Sty/hyper}

\begin{document}

\input{tex/Forkurs-1p-2p-laererutdanning-2018-V-frontmatter.tex}

\input{tex/Forkurs-1p-2p-laererutdanning-2018-V-del-1.tex}

\input{tex/Forkurs-1p-2p-laererutdanning-2018-V-del-2.tex}

\end{document}
```

I am trying to create two commands

```
nmap <leader>en
nmap <leader>ep
```

To increase and decrease the year in the file  and swap H with V and V with H. Invoking `<leader>en` should increase the year when the year is preceeded by an H. e.g `YEAR-H`. While the command should swap H with V and V with H.

```
2018-V
2018-H
2019-V
2019-H
2020-V
2020-H
.
.
.
```

Similarly `<leader>ep` should decrease the numbers when the number is preceeded by V. Always swap V with H and vice versa.

```
2018-V
2017-H
2017-V
2016-H
2016-V
2015-H
.
.
.
```

However I am not sure how to perform a conditional search replace from vim.  Any suggestions?

EDIT: To clarify the increase function should work like this

```
IF H 
   Increase year
Toggle VH (Change H to V and V to H)
```

So *only* increase the year when the text contains `YEAR-H`. *Always* swap H and V.

The decrease function should work similarly

```
IF V
   Decrease year
Toggle VH (Change H to V and V to H)
```

So *only* decrease the year when the text contains `YEAR-V`. *Always* swap H with V and vice-versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The requirements, which were unclear originally, have been updated. Result: much of my original answer is out the window. Here's the new one...*

We can't reasonably wedge logic into global commands and/or Normal mode commands so in this case it makes more sense to use a function...to be called from a [sub-replace-expression](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#sub-replace-expression)

The function:

```
func! ProcessYHV(in, incr) 
    let l:year = strcharpart(a:in, 0, 4)
    let l:code = strcharpart(a:in, 5, 1)
    if l:code == "H"
        if a:incr
            let l:year = l:year + 1
        endif
        let l:code = "V"
    else
        if ! a:incr
            let l:year = l:year - 1
        endif
        let l:code = "H"
    endif
    return l:year . "-" . l:code
endfunc
```

First parameter is a string that matches the key pattern, `\d\{4}-[HV]`, second parameter is "boolean" (0 or 1) that determines if it's an increment or decrement operation, and the function returns the proper replacement string based on the specified logic.

Then we just use this function in a substitution command by leveraging expression evaluation...

```
:%s/\d\{4}-[HV]/\=ProcessYHV(submatch(0), 1)/    " decrement
:%s/\d\{4}-[HV]/\=ProcessYHV(submatch(0), 0)/    " increment
```

This "sub-replace-expression" (help link at beginning of this answer) works like this: everything to the right of the `\=` is evaluated as an expression and the result becomes the replacement text. `submatch(0)` returns the entire pattern match and we're passing that as the first param to our function.

The mappings...

```
:nnoremap <Leader>en :%s/\d\{4}-[HV]/\=ProcessYHV(submatch(0), 1)/<cr>
:nnoremap <Leader>ep :%s/\d\{4}-[HV]/\=ProcessYHV(submatch(0), 0)/<cr>
```

Comment: You were on the right track with sub-replace-expression and  `submatch`.