# Cycle between filenames

Tags: substitute, multiple-files

I have some files with names as below

```
long-ordinary-filename-del-1.tex
long-ordinary-filename-del-2.tex
long-ordinary-filename-del-3.tex
```

Is it possible to define a command to cycle between these files? More concretely if I have `long-ordinary-filename-2.tex` executing the command should take me to `long-ordinary-filename-3.tex` and doing it again should give me `long-ordinary-filename-1.tex`.

I would have posted what I have tried, but I have no idea how to search replace in commands. I know I can get the curent filename using `:pwd` or `expand('%:r')`.

**EDIT:** Using the [solution](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/20257/22594) from my previous question I was able to create this solution

```
" Swaps between similarly named files
func! IncrementDel(in) 
    let l:del = 1 + strcharpart(a:in, 4, 1)
    if l:del > "3"
        let l:del = 1
    endif
    return "del-" . l:del
endfunc

:nnoremap <localleader>nd o<Esc>"%p<S-V>:s/del-\d/\=IncrementDel(submatch(0))/<CR>:nohls<CR>dd:edit <C-r>"<CR>
```

- Pasting into the current file to switch files seems very barbaric, can this be avoided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an argument list of files and cycle through them. Built in `:h :next` won't wrap from last to first, so a custom map or command is necessary:

```
nnoremap <leader>a :exe ( argidx() == argc() - 1 ? 'first' : 'next') <cr>
```

To populate argument list when you start vim:

```
vim long-ordinary-filename-del-*.text
```

To change argument list after you start vim:

```
:args long-ordinary-filename-del-*.text
```

You use `:h :args` to check your current argument list.

**update**

To create a dedicated solution to this problem only:

```
function! s:next_of_3()

  " do nothing if current filename doesn't match
  if @% !~# '\v[123]\.tex$'
    return
  endif

  " open next file
  let fname = substitute(@%, '\v[123]\ze\.tex$', '\=submatch(0)%3+1', '')
  if filereadable(fname)
    exec 'e ' . fname
  endif
endfunction

nnoremap <leader>3 :call <sid>next_of_3()<cr>
```

`:h quote%` is name of current file. `:h :s\=` is used to get the matching text.

Comment: this works great. Is there a way to define a similar command that *decreases* instead of increases? I tried `let fnameA = substitute(@%, '\v[1234]\ze\.', '\(\=submatch(0)-1\)%4', '')` and a few other similar commands, alas nothing worked.

Comment: You can't separate the leading \ and = , otherwise it's a pure string.